# SSO implementation with multiple websites and a main sso website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement SSO to our applications. Here is what I am looking for;

1. User can visit SSO Website without login. This is the main website and user can login to this website.
2. User can reach to Website-1, Website-2 and Website-3 without login.
3. User can login to these websites also.(Website-1, Website-2 and Website-3)
4. If user want to login from these websites he has to be redirected to SSO website to login.
5. If user login any of the websites , he should be logged in at other websites when he visits. For example: User logged in at Website-1(redirect  login from SSO website) and after that he opened the Website-3 and he should be logged in here too.
6. These websites are at different domains.(Not sub-domains)
7. All of them developed with ASP.NET MVC.

So, How can I achieve something like that?

Here is the simple visual.

[image: Simple visual]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724735/federated-services/38729329#38729329

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks for the document but at this document they define authentication mode="Forms" to web.config and this will automatically redirect to login if you are not authenticated. But I don't want this. User can surf freely on websites.

Comment: Even with authentication mode="Forms" you can have parts of the website that will be "open", you'll have to define the [Authorize] attribute on contoller or controller methods to define the parts that need authorization. You can check this document that explains something quite similar to what you want http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc.

Comment: Oh okay, I did that tutorial but couldn't realize the "[Authorize]" filter. Thanks @Gimly